# If $f(x) = f(y) \Longrightarrow g(x) = g(y)$, then determine $\phi$ so $g(x) = \phi(f(x))$

Tags: functions

Let $x$,$y$ $\in I=\{1,...,n\}$, let $F$ and $G$ be some sets, and let $f:I\to F$ and $g:I\to G$ be two maps.

I want to show that $$f(x) = f(y) \Longrightarrow g(x) = g(y) \ \ \text{if and only if}\ \ \exists \phi \colon F \rightarrow G \ \ \text{such that} \ g(x) = \phi(f(x)). $$

If we assume the latter, then if $f(x) = f(y)$, then $g(x) = \phi(f(x)) = \phi(f(y)) = g(y)$, so that holds.

How do I show the other implication?

Comment: $f$ and $g$ are two maps... from where to where?

Comment: From I to F and G respectively.

Answer (score 2):

First, you can define $\phi$ however you want on $F\setminus Im(f)$, it does not matter for your problem.

Then for any $y\in Im(f)$, write $y=f(x)$ and define $\phi(y) = g(x)$.

To see that this is well-defined, you have to check that $g(x)$ does not depend on the choice of $x$ but only on $y$. But if $y=f(x')$ then by hypothesis $g(x')=g(x)$. So $\phi$ is well-defined and satisfies your property.